# Read line by line from a socket buffer

Tags: c, string, sockets, split

I want to write a function that read line by line from a socket buffer obtained from third parameter from `read()` function from `unistd.h` header.

I have wrote this:

```
int sgetline(int fd, char ** out)
{
    int buf_size = 128;
    int bytesloaded = 0;
    char buf[2];
    char * buffer = malloc(buf_size);
    char * newbuf;
    int size = 0;

    assert(NULL != buffer);

    while( read(fd, buf, 1) > 0 )
    {
        strcat(buffer, buf);
        buf[1] = '\0';
        bytesloaded += strlen(buf);
        size = size + buf_size;

        if(buf[0] == '\n')
        {
            *out = buffer; 
            return bytesloaded;
        }

        if(bytesloaded >= size)
        {
            size = size + buf_size;
            newbuf = realloc(buffer, size);

            if(NULL != newbuf)
            {
                buffer = newbuf;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("sgetline() allocation failed!\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    *out = buffer;
    return bytesloaded;
}
```

but I have some problems with this function, for example, if the input is something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n
Cache-Control:no-cache\r\n
Content-Length:0\r\n
Location\r\nhttp://bing.com/\r\n
\r\n\r\n
```

and I do

```
int sockfd = socket( ... );
//....
char* tbuf;
while(sgetline(sockfd, &tbuf) > 0)
{
    if(strcmp(tbuf,"\r\n\r\n") == 0)
    {
       printf("End of Headers detected.\n");
    }
}
```

the above C application does not output `"End of Header detected."`. Why is this, and how can I fix this?

Comment: How can get `Notable question` badge with **0** upvotes haha.

Comment: See the [TLPI's readline](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/sockets/read_line.c.html) implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things more difficult for yourself than they need to be.  You really don't need to do strcats to get the single character you read on each read added at the current position.

But your bug is that the routine returns as soon as it sees a \n, so the string it returns can never contain anything following the first \n.

Answer (score 9):

It's not OK to read one byte at a time, because you are making too many system calls - better is to use a buffer, read a chunk and check if you got \n. After getting a line, the rest of the bytes read remains in the buffer, so you cannot mix read/recv with read_line. Another version of read n bytes using this kind of buffer can be write...

My version to read a line, and a little example to use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CBSIZE 2048

typedef struct cbuf {
    char buf[CBSIZE];
    int fd;
    unsigned int rpos, wpos;
} cbuf_t;


int read_line(cbuf_t *cbuf, char *dst, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    ssize_t n;
    while (i < size) {
        if (cbuf->rpos == cbuf->wpos) {
            size_t wpos = cbuf->wpos % CBSIZE;
            //if ((n = read(cbuf->fd, cbuf->buf + wpos, (CBSIZE - wpos))) < 0) {
            if((n = recv(cbuf->fd, cbuf->buf + wpos, (CBSIZE - wpos), 0)) < 0) {
                if (errno == EINTR)
                    continue;
                return -1;
            } else if (n == 0)
                return 0;
            cbuf->wpos += n;
        }
        dst[i++] = cbuf->buf[cbuf->rpos++ % CBSIZE];
        if (dst[i - 1] == '\n')
            break;
    }
    if(i == size) {
         fprintf(stderr, "line too large: %d %d\n", i, size);
         return -1;
    }

    dst[i] = 0;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cbuf_t *cbuf;
    char buf[512];
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct hostent *h;
    char *ip;
    char host[] = "www.google.com";

    if(!(h = gethostbyname(host))) {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        return NULL;
    }
    ip = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr*)h->h_addr);

    cbuf = calloc(1, sizeof(*cbuf));

    fprintf(stdout, "Connecting to ip: %s\n", ip);
    if((cbuf->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));
    saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(80);
    inet_aton(ip, &saddr.sin_addr);
    if(connect(cbuf->fd, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        perror("connect");
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n", host);
    write(cbuf->fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    while(read_line(cbuf, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
        // if it's an empty \r\n on a line, header ends //
        if(buf[0]=='\r' && buf[1] == '\n') {
            printf("------------------------\n");
        }
        printf("[%s]", buf);
    }
    close(cbuf->fd);
    free(cbuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this implementation instead:

```
int sgetline(int fd, char ** out) 
{ 
    int buf_size = 0; 
    int in_buf = 0; 
    int ret;
    char ch; 
    char * buffer = NULL; 
    char * new_buffer;

    do
    {
        // read a single byte
        ret = read(fd, &ch, 1);
        if (ret < 1)
        {
            // error or disconnect
            free(buffer);
            return -1;
        }

        // has end of line been reached?
        if (ch == '\n') 
            break; // yes

        // is more memory needed?
        if ((buf_size == 0) || (in_buf == buf_size)) 
        { 
            buf_size += 128; 
            new_buffer = realloc(buffer, buf_size); 

            if (!new_buffer) 
            { 
                free(buffer);
                return -1;
            } 

            buffer = new_buffer; 
        } 

        buffer[in_buf] = ch; 
        ++in_buf; 
    } 
    while (true);

    // if the line was terminated by "\r\n", ignore the
    // "\r". the "\n" is not in the buffer
    if ((in_buf > 0) && (buffer[in_buf-1] == '\r'))
        --in_buf;

    // is more memory needed?
    if ((buf_size == 0) || (in_buf == buf_size)) 
    { 
        ++buf_size; 
        new_buffer = realloc(buffer, buf_size); 

        if (!new_buffer) 
        { 
            free(buffer);
            return -1;
        } 

        buffer = new_buffer; 
    } 

    // add a null terminator
    buffer[in_buf] = '\0';

    *out = buffer; // complete line

    return in_buf; // number of chars in the line, not counting the line break and null terminator
}
```

```
int sockfd = socket( ... );         
//....         
char* tbuf;         
int ret;

// keep reading until end of headers is detected.
// headers are terminated by a 0-length line
do
{
    // read a single line
    ret = sgetline(sockfd, &tbuf);
    if (ret < 0)
        break; // error/disconnect

    // is it a 0-length line?
    if (ret == 0)
    {
       printf("End of Headers detected.\n");         
       free(tbuf);
       break;
    }

    // tbuf contains a header line, use as needed...

    free(tbuf);
}
while (true);
```

Comment: Looks to me like that would break on the first occurrence of "\r\n" rather than the first occurrence of "\r\n\r\n".  If I'm missing something, then this is overly clever for the lack of comments.

Comment: The function reads 1 line and 1 line only. It is supposed to exit when it encounters a `\n` character, and it supports both `\r\n` and `\n` style line breaks (HTTP says to use `\r\n` only, but some third-party implementations use `\n` instead). HTTP headers are terminated by a blank line.  The function returns the number of characters in the returned line, not counting the line break. The code calls the function in a loop until a 0-length line is encountered.

Comment: I have added comments.  You don't check for `\r\n\r\n` together, you check for a line that is just `\r\n` by itself.

Comment: What is about performance, if you read just 1 byte per call of read()? Is there any optimization applied in background, because the function would be called extremely often?

Comment: The socket has an internal buffer that `read()` reads from. But, if you are worried about performance (and you should use a profiler to judge that), you can always use an intermediate buffer to `read()` more than 1 byte into at a time, scanning that buffer for the desired bytes and copying them to the output buffer, going back to the socket for more bytes only when needed. That will cut down on the number of calls to `read()`, and will get more bytes out of the socket to keep its internal buffer rolling so transmissions are less likely to block.

Comment: strings from this are not null terminated. Should add `buffer[bytesloaded] = 0;` in the end.

Comment: @PoVa that has intentional, since the function returns the number of characters in the line, so a null terminator is not necessary. But I added a null terminator now, just in  case

Comment: @RemyLebeau what's the point of `if ((buf_size == 0) || (in_buf == buf_size)) ` after the loop?

Comment: @PoVa the same point as inside the loop. It checks if `buffer` needs to be (re)allocated before appending more data to it. After the loop, a null terminator is added. If the very first thing read is a line break then `buffer` may not have been allocated yet. If the final line length is an even multiple of 128 characters without the line break then `buffer` is full and has to grow 1 more byte to accommodate the null terminator.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Your routine causes memory leak!!

Comment: @IshanKarve no, it doesn't, when used properly. If you are experiencing leaks, you are not using it correctly