# How to insert data into a .csv file sent by a client?

Tags: c, sockets, csv

Could anyone help me to insert the data into a .csv file?

The code which I have written writes the data into a .csv file.

I am trying to display the IP address of the client in it. But it is displayed as shown in the figure.

[image]

But I want my .csv file to be displayed as,

[image]

This is the code which writes the data into a .csv file.

```
    //included all header files

int main()
{
int new_sockfd,new1_sockfd,x1,x2,log,n;
int server_len, client_len;
struct sockaddr_in serveraddress;
struct sockaddr_in client_address;
int buffsize=1024;
char buffer2[1024];

if((new_sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))>0)

printf("\n ***************************** Interface Server *******************************\n");    
printf("\n Socket was created\n");

serveraddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serveraddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
serveraddress.sin_port = ntohs(9735);
server_len = sizeof(serveraddress);

bind(new_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddress, server_len);

listen(new_sockfd, 5);
while(1)
    {        
         char ch;             
         printf("\n\n Interface Server waiting...\n");

client_len = sizeof(client_address);

new1_sockfd = accept(new_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);

if (new1_sockfd==-1) { perror("Connection Not Accepted!!"); return(1);}
else
        printf("\n Task agent is connected\n");    
//*********************
 //displays client adddress
 FILE * I= fopen("final_report.csv","a+");
 fprintf(I,"%s,",inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr));
 fclose(I);
//*********************
 printf("\n Final Report has been generated\n\n");

 log=open("final_report.csv",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_APPEND,0777);
       if(log==-1)
         {
             perror("cannot open the Final Report\n");
             return(1);
         }
       do
         {              
             x1=read(new1_sockfd, buffer2,1024); 
             x2=write(log,buffer2,x1);
         }
        while (x1>0);
 close(log); 
 close(new1_sockfd);  
  }
}
```

Basically using my program the client address is displayed only in one row, but I need it in every row.

Because I am using multiple client machines to send the data and I need to find out which client(IP adddress) has sent it.

I have tried, but was unable to find the solution for this. Could anyone please guide me to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right now you're reading from the socket in 1024-byte chunks. If you read line by line instead, you can read one line of CSV data, parse it into fields, and insert whatever fields you like before writing the result. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828752/read-line-by-line-from-a-socket-buffer for some guidance on how to read data from a socket line by line.

Comment: I din't understand it sir

Answer (score 0):

On a long shot, perhaps the data written by fprintf(I,"%s,",inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr)); statement is buffered and gets overwritten, which deletes the address. Perhaps calling fflush may solve the problem.

Could you share the raw data read in this line (content of buffer2)
x1=read(new1_sockfd, buffer2,1024);

Comment: content of bufffer2 is same data except the ip address. (this  is actually a interface server where i need to apply weka tool on these tuples)

Answer (score 0):

> If you read line by line instead, you can read one line of CSV data,
>   parse it into fields, and insert whatever fields you like before
>   writing the result. – Tim Pierce

To this effect, change your code after the `printf("\n Task agent is connected\n");` to something like

```
//*********************
 FILE *I = fopen("final_report.csv", "a+"), *stream = fdopen(new1_sockfd, "r");
       if (!I)
         {
             perror("cannot open the Final Report");
             return 1;
         }

 while (fgets(buffer2, sizeof buffer2, stream))
  //displays client adddress
  fprintf(I, "%s,%s", inet_ntoa(client_address.sin_addr), buffer2);
 fclose(I);
//*********************
 printf("\n Final Report has been generated\n\n");
 fclose(stream);  
  }
}
```