# How can i read html page line by line using recv?

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I tried to practice socket programming using C language.
What I was trying do is to read certain html page line by line which means read until '\n'. 
The problem is, though, because of recv's attribute of reading certain amount of length which we pass as a argument to third argument of recv().
For example,

```
char buff[256];
.
.
recv(socknumber, buf, sizeof(buff), 0);
```

In this case, recv read string as much as sizeof(buff). So I had no idea how to deal with '\n'

Since I'm a C virgin, please give me some tip, or simple code. Thanks.

Comment: On modern POSIX systems `recv` is equivalent to `read` if you don't pass any flags and you may try using `fdopen` to parse the socket as a regular stdio `FILE`, e.g. with `fgets` or whatnot to extract the lines. Unfortunately this won't work with Winsock on Windows systems.

Comment: "html page line by line". HTML pages do not consist of lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement it by yourself because there is no concept of line in socket transmissions. There is a lot of solution even in SO, see that one [read line by line from a socket buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828752/read-line-by-line-from-a-socket-buffer). You can also get a `FILE` handle from your socket descriptor and use `*gets` functions (have a look at `fdopen`if you are on Unix).

Answer (score 1):

There is no `standard` implementation for your requirement.  What you need to do is have a proper `sending` and a `receiving` socket programs.

A suggestion method :

- `Sender` reads the HTML file chunk by chunk (lets say 100 bytes per one read) and send them to `reciever`
- `Receiver` accepts data chunk sent by sender and write to the file.
  (receiver knows the size of a chunk)
- You can specify the file length before starting transmission.

What you would need :

- C file read and write : [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_file_io.htm)
- C socket programming : [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/)

Furthermore : Here are example code set from me

"`Client` requests the file by name and `server` response file if available, chunk by chunk"

Server :

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define SIZE 1024


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    /*Variable set*/
    int listenfd,connfd,n,size;
    FILE * ff;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    socklen_t clilen;
    char buffer[SIZE];

    /* Dedicated socket to listening */
    listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    /* Initialize a sockaddr_in struct with our own address information for binding the socket */
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

    /* Binding */
    bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

    /*Listening to the socket*/
    listen(listenfd,0);
    clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);

    /*Wait till a client request a file*/
    connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen); // the uninitialized cliaddr variable is filled in with the
    n = recvfrom(connfd,buffer,SIZE ,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);// information of the client by recvfrom function
    buffer[n] = '\0';

    printf("CLient requested %s:\n",buffer);

    /*Trying to open requested file*/
    ff=fopen(buffer,"r");
    if(ff==NULL){
        printf("Request file not found..!!\n");
        strcpy(buffer,"NACK");
        sendto(connfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr)); 
        return(0); //exit
    }

    /*If file is availbe - Find the size of file*/
    fseek(ff,0L,SEEK_END);
    size=ftell(ff);

    fseek(ff,0L,SEEK_SET);
    sprintf(buffer,"%d",size);

    /*Send size of file*/
    sendto(connfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));


    /*Sits in a loop and send 1000 byte chunks -Uppon ACK's from client*/

    int i;
    int t=TRUE;
    char c;

    while(t){

        /*Recieve client flag*/
        n = recvfrom(connfd,buffer,SIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
        buffer[n] = 0;

        /*If its not ACK then exit*/
        if(strcmp(buffer,"ACK")){
            printf("CLient failled to grab data chunks..\n");
            return(0);
        }

        /*Else read 1000 bytes*/
        for(i=0;i<1000;i++){
            c=fgetc(ff);
            buffer[i]=c;
            if(c==EOF){
                t=FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }

        /*Send red data chunk*/
        sendto(connfd,buffer,i,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
        printf("Sending.. %d bytes \n",i);
    }

    /*Close file*/
    fclose(ff);


    return 0;
}
```

Client :

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/*Macros*/
#define SIZE 1024
#define TRUE 1

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    /*Variable Set*/
    int sockfd,n,len;
    FILE * ff;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    char buffer[SIZE];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("usage:  ./%s <IP address>\n",argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    /* socket to connect */
    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    /* IP address information of the server to connect to */ 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    /*Ask user to specify required file name*/
    printf("What's the required file ? ");
    scanf("%s",buffer);

    /*Send requested file name to server*/
    sendto(sockfd,buffer,SIZE,0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,SIZE,0,NULL,NULL);
    buffer[n]=0;

    /*If server found that file is not present it sends a NACK*/
    if(!strcmp(buffer,"NACK")){
        printf("Required file not in server..\n");
        return(1);
    }

    /*Else server send the size of the file*/
    printf("FIle size is %s bytes \n",buffer);
    len=atoi(buffer);

    /* Open/create file to save recieved data*/
    ff=fopen("clientfile.txt","w"); /*OPen or create the file to be written*/

    /*Check for file creation success*/
    if(ff==NULL){
        strcpy(buffer,"NACK");
        sendto(sockfd,buffer,SIZE,0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
        printf("File creating failled.. \n");
        return(0);
    }


    /*Client stays in a loop till it recieve full data*/
    int c=0;
    while(c<len){

        /*Each time client sends ACK to recieve next data chunk*/
        strcpy(buffer,"ACK");
        sendto(sockfd,buffer,SIZE,0, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

        n=recvfrom(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0,NULL,NULL);
        printf("Recieved %d bytes\n",n);

        /*Increase counter by recieve chunk size*/
        c+=n;

        /*Add null character to end of data*/
        if(c>=len){
            buffer[n]='\0';
        }

        /*Append to file*/
        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),n,ff);
    }

    fclose(ff);
    printf("File sucessfully recieved..\n");
    return 0;
}
```